# Search is not clearing last record from grid

Tags: jquery, json

Below are the functions for search button and grid load.First click of search works fine but on second click it will not clear old record. Can you please help me out where I am wrong

```
SpecialtySearch_OnClick: function (SpecialtyId) {

    if ($("#pnlAdminSpecialty #pnlSpecialty_Result").css("display") == "none") {
        $("#pnlAdminSpecialty #pnlSpecialty_Result").show();
    }

    var self = $("#pnlSpecialty_Search");
    var myJSON = self.getMyJSON();

    Admin_Specialty.SearchSpecialty(myJSON, SpecialtyId).done(function (response) {
        if (response.status != false) {
            Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyGridLoad(response);
        }
        else {
        }
    });
},

SpecialtyGridLoad: function (response) {

    $("#pnlSpecialty_Result #dgvSpecialty tbody").find("tr").remove();
    if (response.SpecialtyCount > 0) {
        var SpecialtyLoadJSONData = JSON.parse(response.SpecialtyLoad_JSON);
        $.each(SpecialtyLoadJSONData, function (i, item) {
            var $row = $('<tr/>');
            $row.attr("onclick", "utility.SelectGridRow($('#gvSpecialty_row" + item.SpecialtyId + "'))");
            $row.attr("id", "gvSpecialty_row" + item.SpecialtyId);
            $row.attr("SpecialtyId", item.SpecialtyId);

            if (item.IsActive == "True")
                $row.append('<td style="display:none;">' + item.SpecialtyId + '</td><td><a class="btn  btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyDelete(' + item.SpecialtyId + ');" title="Delete Record"><i class="fa fa-close red"></i></a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyEdit(' + item.SpecialtyId + ');" title="Edit Record"><i class="fa fa-edit black"></i></a>&nbsp;<a class="btn  btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyActiveInactive(' + item.SpecialtyId + ', 0);" title="Inactive Record"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off black"></i></a></td><td>' + item.ShortName + '</td><td>' + item.Description + '</td>');
            else
                $row.append('<td style="display:none;">' + item.SpecialtyId + '</td><td><a class="btn  btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyDelete(' + item.SpecialtyId + ');" title="Delete Record"><i class="fa fa-close red"></i></a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyEdit(' + item.SpecialtyId + ');" title="Edit Record"><i class="fa fa-edit black"></i></a>&nbsp;<a class="btn  btn-xs" href="#" onclick="Admin_Specialty.SpecialtyActiveInactive(' + item.SpecialtyId + ', 1);" title="Active Record"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on green"></i></a></td><td>' + item.ShortName + '</td><td>' + item.Description + '</td>');

            $("#pnlSpecialty_Result #dgvSpecialty tbody").last().append($row);
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#pnlSpecialty_Result #dgvSpecialty").parent().append("<table class='table table-bordered table-striped table-hover mb-none'><tr><td>No provider found</td></tr></table>");
    }
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#dgvSpecialty'))
        ;
    else
        $("#pnlSpecialty_Result #dgvSpecialty").DataTable({ "bLengthChange": false }); // to remove records per page dropdown
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved, Actually in my case data table reinitialized on search button click and I am not destroying first created data table.

```
$("#dgvSpecialty").dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Works for me or you can dynamically create table with in data table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
        "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
        "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "No records available",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
} );
} );
```